# Grouping web sessions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Objective is to group transnational information on user actions into sessions by timeout between said records. (In example: Same user preform 10 actions within 1-3 minutes in between each -> session #1; and 2 hours after another 10 actions again with few minutes in between -> session #2)

Sample input:

```
id    user_id    trans_datetime
1     1          2017-03-16 07:12:01
2     2          2017-03-16 07:12:02
3     2          2017-03-16 07:12:12
4     1          2017-03-16 08:57:00
5     1          2017-03-16 08:58:01
6     1          2017-03-16 09:01:50
7     1          2017-03-16 10:14:01
8     1          2017-03-16 10:18:01
9     1          2017-03-16 10:35:11
```

Expected output:

```
id  start_id user_id    trans_datetime
1   1        1          2017-03-16 07:12:01
2   2        2          2017-03-16 07:12:02
3   2        2          2017-03-16 07:12:12
4   4        1          2017-03-16 08:57:00
5   4        1          2017-03-16 08:58:01
6   4        1          2017-03-16 09:01:50
7   7        1          2017-03-16 10:14:01
8   7        1          2017-03-16 10:18:01
9   7        1          2017-03-16 10:35:11
```

My initial idea was to use Recursive CTE as:

```
With rCTE as (
 Select id 
   ,id as start_id
   ,user_id
   ,tran_datetime
 from transactions
 where first_transaction_flg = 1

Union all

Select child.id
   ,parent.id as start_id
   ,child.user_id
   ,child.tran_datetime
from transactions child
 Inner Join rCTE parent
 on child.user_id = parent.user_id
  and child.tran_datetime > parent.datetime
  and datediff(minute, child.tran_datetime, parent.tran_datetime) < 20
)
Select * from rCTE
```

But it does not seem to work as intended, and i can't quite put my finger on why.

Comment: please explain with some sample data,add expected result in form of text

Comment: What version are you working with?

Comment: @ZoharPeled 2014

Comment: In your code you are joining based on an hour difference, but your expected results start a new session for `user_id 1` at `2017-03-16 08:57:00` when their last action was 45 minutes ago at `2017-03-16 08:12:12`. What is the time between actions to count as a single session?

Comment: @SqlZim sorry, just poor example, main idea is to separate sessions by certain timeout. I'll update question.

Answer (score 1):

using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with a subquery to check if there is a valid previous activity for each `trans_datetime`, and an [**`outer apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
;with ses as (
  select 
      t.*
    , prevTime = (
        select max(i.trans_datetime) 
        from t as i
        where i.user_id = t.user_id
          and i.trans_datetime < t.trans_datetime
          and i.trans_datetime >= dateadd(hour,-1,t.trans_datetime)
        )
  from t
)
select 
    id
  , start_id = case 
      when prevTime is null 
        then id 
      else x.start_id
      end
  , user_id
  , trans_datetime
from ses
outer apply (
  select top 1
    start_id = id
  from ses i
  where i.user_id = ses.user_id 
    and i.trans_datetime < ses.trans_datetime
    and i.prevTime is null
  order by trans_datetime desc
    ) x
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/CGJSX81463

returns:

```
+----+----------+---------+---------------------+
| id | start_id | user_id |   trans_datetime    |
+----+----------+---------+---------------------+
|  1 |        1 |       1 | 2017-03-16 07:12:01 |
|  2 |        2 |       2 | 2017-03-16 07:12:02 |
|  3 |        2 |       2 | 2017-03-16 07:12:12 |
|  4 |        4 |       1 | 2017-03-16 08:57:00 |
|  5 |        4 |       1 | 2017-03-16 08:58:01 |
|  6 |        4 |       1 | 2017-03-16 09:01:50 |
|  7 |        7 |       1 | 2017-03-16 10:14:01 |
|  8 |        7 |       1 | 2017-03-16 10:18:01 |
|  9 |        7 |       1 | 2017-03-16 10:35:11 |
+----+----------+---------+---------------------+
```